# Integrate $\int \frac{x}{x^4-a^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate $\displaystyle \int \frac{x}{x^4-a^4}dx$.

My approach:

$$\begin{align}\displaystyle\int \frac{x}{x^4-a^4}dx&=\int\frac{x}{(x^2)^2-a^4}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u^2-(a^2)^2}\tag{by substituting $u=x^2$}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{1}{a^2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{a^2}\right)+C\right ]\\
&=-\frac{1}{2a^2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)+C\
\end{align}$$

I am not sure if we were allowed to use $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+C$ just like in the third equality.

Am I mistaken here? why I think we can is that $u^2-(a^2)^2 = u^2+(-(a^2))^2$.

The book gives:$\displaystyle\frac{1}{4a^2}\ln\left| \frac{x^2-a^2}{x^2+a^2} \right| +C$.

Regardless, does my solution work? Thanks.

Comment: Be careful that that's a $-$ not a $+$.

Comment: tt is not an arctan, using your approach the next step is partial fractions, But I would do partial fractions before substituting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(-(a^2))^2 = a^4$, so that's not the same thing.

The key is to use partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{u^2- a^4} = \frac{1}{(u-a^2)(u + a^2)} = \frac{1}{2a^2} \left(\frac{1}{u - a^2} - \frac{1}{u + a^2} \right)$$